# How to raspberry pi 3 less than 1 second boot?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, yocto, buildroot

I have a question

I need a fast boot raspberry pi 3 image, I have done an image and it is booting up in 3.5 seconds, but I need more than that which is around 1 second.

also another silly question is, how we can pass quickly the rainbow splash screen in raspberry pi startup because it takes around 1.2 seconds while initializing the boot process.

thanks for your answers.

Comment: As of right now, this question seems rather noisy and off topic while making little sense. If possible, please edit it to make it more clear and on-topic

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to an in depth look at boot time optimizations. https://elinux.org/images/6/64/Chris-simmonds-boot-time-elce-2017_0.pdf. I am not repeating it here as it is *long*. It outlines how to profile your boot speed and then how to optimize each stage of the boot process. I encourage you to use this as a reference how to start, and as you attempt optimizations, come back with more specific questions.

Another way to profile which I don't think is mentioned in the presentation is to toggle a gpio at each stage of the boot process (bootloader, kernel, userspace). Using an oscilloscope to compare the reset line and the gpio will give you a quick look at what stages take the longest, and start optimizing there.

With regards to the splash screen: The RPi may not be idling while the splash screen is present. It may for example display the splash screen during the bootloader stage and immediately start loading the linux kernel. After the boot process is finished, a virtual terminal could be displayed by the kernel.